# Rails where clause is not working for some of the values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am working on Easy Redmine PMS and I have written where query in rails Like:

```
Tracker.where(name: "+ Permits Required")
```

but it returns less values whereas when I have tried detect query for getting same data Like:

```
Tracker.all.detect{|i| i.name == "+ Permits Required"
```

And it is returning all the values. Also I noticed that when fetching the data directly in database then I get the value as `Request Available` whereas rails console returns `Permits Required`. I have tried this issue with postgresql and mysql both the databases and the issue is same. Here are the queries:

```
2.1.1 :001 > @tra = Tracker.find_by_name("+ Camps & Finished Food Store")
  Tracker Load (32.8ms)  SELECT  "trackers".* FROM "trackers" WHERE "trackers"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "+ Camps & Finished Food Store"]]
 => nil 
2.1.1 :002 > @tra = Tracker.all.detect{|i| i.name == ("+ Camps & Finished Food Store")}
  Tracker Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "trackers".* FROM "trackers"
  AnonymousUser Load (27.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('AnonymousUser')  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  EasyTranslation Load (28.6ms)  SELECT  "easy_translations".* FROM "easy_translations" WHERE "easy_translations"."entity_id" = $1 AND "easy_translations"."entity_type" = $2 AND "easy_translations"."entity_column" = $3 AND "easy_translations"."lang" = $4  ORDER BY "easy_translations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["entity_id", 3], ["entity_type", "Tracker"], ["entity_column", "name"], ["lang", "en"]]
  EasyTranslation Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "easy_translations".* FROM "easy_translations" WHERE "easy_translations"."entity_id" = $1 AND "easy_translations"."entity_type" = $2 AND "easy_translations"."entity_column" = $3 AND "easy_translations"."lang" = $4  ORDER BY "easy_translations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["entity_id", 4], ["entity_type", "Tracker"], ["entity_column", "name"], ["lang", "en"]]
  EasyTranslation Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "easy_translations".* FROM "easy_translations" WHERE "easy_translations"."entity_id" = $1 AND "easy_translations"."entity_type" = $2 AND "easy_translations"."entity_column" = $3 AND "easy_translations"."lang" = $4  ORDER BY "easy_translations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["entity_id", 5], ["entity_type", "Tracker"], ["entity_column", "name"], ["lang", "en"]]
2.1.1 :003 > @tra = Tracker.where(name: "+ Camps & Finished Food Store")
  Tracker Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "trackers".* FROM "trackers" WHERE "trackers"."name" = $1  [["name", "+ Camps & Finished Food Store"]]
```

Comment: Why are you using '+ Test' ?

Comment: `"+ Test"` is not the same `"Test"`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add '+' for detect query.

Comment: What Trackers are missing? What are found? What SQL quer is executed?

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Tracker.where(name: "Permits Required")